# What are my options for making Power BI Direct Query reports run faster?

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Power BI report that has between 6-12 visuals with each having their own direct query that pulls the data from Snowflake. The reason this report is using direct query is because users enter data into Snowflake and want to see their results immediately after they have entered in a batch of data. So a scheduled refresh is not an option.

It can take the report anywhere from 5-20 seconds to load a page. How do I get this down to under 5 seconds?

So far I have enabled the report to load the tables in parallel. I didn't notice any gains from that change. I also notice that I lose a few seconds due to the Warehouse spinning up from being suspended. So there isn't anything I can do for that. as we don't want to run the warehouse 24/7.

FYI, the current queries return around 10-50 rows each with 3-5 columns. There isn't much data being loaded.

A few options I was thinking of.

Would a larger warehouse improve the query time or run more queries in parallel. I am not sure if it is the Power BI Service or Snowflake that is throttling the number of queries that run in parallel

The other option I am thinking of is trying to merge all the views into one query. I thought about using Materialized Views but, there isn't much data, MVs don't allow for multiple tables to be referenced in a view.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

1. Check the performance of the report when Snowflake is querying the tables and when it is using cache. If the performance is the same/similar in both cases then the bottleneck is in your network/PowerBi rather than in Snowflake. If you re-start the WH and set the USE_CACHED_RESULT = FALSE it should query the tables and then if you set USE_CACHED_RESULT = TRUE and re-run it should use the cache - you can check in the Snowflake history which way it is running
2. Check that nothing else is running using the same WH as your report

If your conclusion is that some (or all) of the performance issue is in Snowflake then:

3. Are the queries running sequentially, in parallel or in a combination of the two?
4. Are any of the queries running particularly slowly and, if so, can you tune them?

If you have slow running queries that you have tuned as best you can:

5. Try increasing the size of your warehouse
6. If queries are running serially, and assuming you have the appropriate license, you could try auto-scaling the WH. However this is unlikely to work as the lag in starting up the additional WHs may well be greater than the performance issue you are trying to reduce

Comment: I'm a little confused on where to run these commands. Do I run these in a worksheet with the warehouse selected.
1. In a worksheet run ALTER SESSION SET USE_CACHED_RESULT = FALSE
2. Open the Power BI report which would cause the direct query to run
3.In the worksheet run ALTER SESSION SET USE_CACHED_RESULT = TRUE
4. Review history

Comment: I don't think you can issue these commands via the PowerBI connection and therefore you'll need to set them for the user that is configured in that connection e.g. "ALTER USER powerbi_user SET USE_CACHED_RESULT = FALSE". You'll need to run this in a Snowflake worksheet but it is not specific to a WH (as it's at the USER level)